# Не работает маленький парсер на Python

Tags: python, парсер

Не работает код. Задача, стоящая передо мной - написать парсер, который собирал бы информацию о всех существующих туристических поездках (название поездки, дата проведения, цена, фото). При работе данного кода не возвращается вообще ничего, как будто бы функция print вообще не отрабатывает.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://turclub-pik.ru/search/region/altaj/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
trips = soup.find_all('div', class_='trip_card')

for n, i in enumerate(trips, start=1):
    tripName = i.find('p', class_='trip_card_title').text.strip()
    tripPrice = i.find('p', class_='trip-card-price').text
    print(f'{n}: {tripName} за {tripPrice}')
```

Если упростить код до хотя бы получения одного параметра (название тур.поездки), то данный код возвращает дублирующиеся названия и, казалось бы, не относящиеся строки (вроде "осталось 6 мест", "мест нет") - возможно проблема разметки страницы. И, прошу заметить, что в 7-й строке в значении класса приходится прописывать именно head, поскольку только так этот код +- работает, хотя по хорошему, тут должен быть class='trip_card' но в данном случае код просто ничего не вернет, и как тогда добавлять отбор других составляющих (дата, стоимость) не понятно.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://turclub-pik.ru/search/region/altaj/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
trips = soup.find_all('div', class_='head')

for trip_card_title in trips:
    print(trip_card_title.text)
```

Так или иначе у меня в планах доработать именно первый код, так как +- поняла логику работы. Пол дня уже мучаюсь с этой проблемой и никак не найду решения) В любом случае, буду рада любой помощи!

**P.S.**
Если в самом верхнем коде менять класс у переменной trips на head (я знаю что не правильно в пределах данного сайта, но так хотя бы, по идее, код должен в нем распознать заголовок tripName) тогда в данном случае вылетает ошибка в 10-ой строке: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**

Comment: Введите `print(soup)` и смотрите есть ли в коде те элементы. Вариант 2, более крутой: в инспекторе браузера для того сайта отключайте javascript (в firefox это в настройках инспектора) и посмотрите на страницу, возможно те теги сайт подгружает через скрипты

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его галочкой как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не python программист, поэтому на правильность кода не претендую, но вариант рабочий

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    response = requests.get('https://turclub-pik.ru/search/region/altaj/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    trips = soup.find_all(True, {"class": ["column", "is-multiline"]})

    for row in trips:
        if row.find('p', class_='trip-card-title') is not None:
            title = row.find('p', class_="trip-card-title").text
            date = row.find('p', class_="trip-card-description").find('span').text
            img = "https://turclub-pik.ru" + row.find('div', class_='cover').find('picture').find('img')['data-src']
            mil = row.find('div', class_='trip-card-info is-flex').find('p', class_='trip-card-length').text
            price = row.find('div', class_='trip-card-footer').find('p', class_='trip-card-price').text
            print(f'title: {title}\n date: {date} \n img: {img} \n mil: {mil} \n price: {price.strip()}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю от все души за помощь! И отдельное спасибо за добавление остальных параметров, я даже и не надеялась, хотела хотя бы с остальными разобраться)

Answer (score 2):

По сути, только парсер поменял на `html.parser`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://turclub-pik.ru/search/region/altaj/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
trips = soup.find_all('div', class_='trip-card')

for i, trip in enumerate(trips, 1):
    tripName = n.find('p', class_='trip-card-title').text.strip()
    tripPrice = n.find('p', class_='trip-card-price').text.strip()
    # if tripPrice:
    #     tripPrice = tripPrice.text.strip()
    print(f'{i}: {tripName} за {tripPrice}')
```

исправно выводит:

```
1: Алтай без рюкзаков. Путешествие по "Золотому кольцу Алтая" за 62 000 ₽
2: Алтай без рюкзаков. Путешествие по "Золотому кольцу Алтая" за 62 000 ₽
3: Алтай. К подножию Белухи за 29 500 ₽
4: Алтай. Треккинг к горным озерам за 29 900 ₽
5: Алтай. Шавлинские озера за 26 900 ₽
6: Детский Алтай за 52 000 ₽
7: Алтай. К подножию Белухи за 29 500 ₽
8: Алтай. Шавлинские озера за 26 900 ₽
9: Алтай. Мультинские озёра за от 19 600 ₽
10: Горнолыжный выезд в Шерегеш. Снежная Сибирь за от 28 500 ₽
11: Восхождение на г.Белуха за от 48 000 ₽
12: Зимний Алтай. Чемал и Мультинские озера за от 52 000 ₽
13: Корпоративные выезды с ПИКом за от 44 400 ₽
```

Comment: Интересно) из-за замены одного параметра заработало. Буду изучать тогда в чем отличие. Спасибо большое за помощь!